# iOS PWA Safari cannot open the page?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

If I do the following on my iPad Pro 11 inch:

1. Turn off Wifi and turn on airplane mode
2. Open our iOS PWA

It says “Safari cannot open the page “http://www.example.com” because your iPad is not connected to the internet.”

1. If I then turn on Wifi and turn off airplane mode, it still has the same message.
2. If I force-close the iOS app and open it again it still has the same message.
3. If I delete the PWA and reinstall it then the message goes away.
4. Or if I shut down the iPad and restart it, the message goes away.

I don’t have any PWA service workers and haven’t really looked into what they are and what is needed. Do I need to have one to eliminate the behaviour described? And if so, what should it be?

Comment: Have you tried to reset your network settings?

Comment: @jess Which ones?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. One workaround is to go to Settings -> Safari and delete the browser cache.